# How to split circles in 8 quadrants

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, geometry

I am using ArcGis 9.3 and I need to split a large number of circles in quadrants. The circles corresponde to a 200m buffer of a point layer and, for each point, I need to split the buffer in 8 quadrants. Is there any ArcGis tool or extension that does this for all points/buffers at the same time?

Comment: So you you want to split each circle into 8 pie-like wedges?  Is that correct?  If not, can you provide a graphic of what you are after?

Answer (score 6):

I've written a script for 10.1/10.2, however you might see if it is possible to rewrite it for 9.3. I've almost never used `arcgisscripting`, but I guess it would be hard to implement the same without [arcpy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/) in 10.0+. [Bearing Distance To Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Bearing_Distance_To_Line/0017000000ts000000/) GP tool I've used is available only in 10.0+, too.

If 9.3 is your only option, you could try to generate the lines with [arcgisscripting](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geoprocessor_object) in 9.3 (with the same logic as I've used with arcpy in the code below) and then use ET Geowizards [Partition Polygons with Polylines](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/partitionPolygonsWithPolylines.htm) which works similar to [Feature To Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Feature_To_Polygon/00170000003n000000/) GP tool in ArcGIS. Another tool that looks promising is [Points To Pie Segments](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/et_geowizards_userguide.htm) from ET Geowizards.

If you will be able to get 10.1+ via evaluation license or if you upgrade, then you could use this script. All other users who find this post and are on 10.1+ could also benefit from using this script. This script assumes your source points you've used for buffering represent the centroid of the output buffer circles.

```py
import arcpy, math

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb"
tempworkspace = arcpy.env.workspace
in_poly_fc = r"C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\CirclesFeatureClass"
clip_lines_fc = r"ClipLines"
sum_lines_fc = r"SumClipLines"

#converting an existing fc with circles to Geometry objects
geometries = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_poly_fc,arcpy.Geometry())

for feature in geometries:
    #obtaining a centroid of the circle centroid via Geometry class attribute
    centroid_Point = feature.trueCentroid
    centroid_xy = []

    #obtaining XY coordinates of the centroid via Point class attribute
    centroid_xy.append(centroid_Point.X)
    centroid_xy.append(centroid_Point.Y)

    #obtaining the radius
    #have to add a small overhead value to make sure the radius end point will overshoot the polygon
    #otherwise may get undershooting lines which depends on the precision of the coordinates
    #and XY tolerance of the source data
    radius = math.sqrt(feature.area / math.pi) + 1

    #supply the list of angles for bearing
    bearing_angles = [0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360]

    #creating bearing angles table and adding fields
    bearing_table = arcpy.CreateTable_management(tempworkspace,"BearingDataTable")
    arcpy.AddField_management(bearing_table,"Xcoord","Double")
    arcpy.AddField_management(bearing_table,"Ycoord","Double")
    arcpy.AddField_management(bearing_table,"Bearing","Double")
    arcpy.AddField_management(bearing_table,"Distance","Double")

    #inserting all required lines constructed from centroid with the radius and bearing angle
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(bearing_table,["Xcoord","Ycoord","Bearing","Distance"]) as ins_cursor:
        for bearing_angle in bearing_angles:
            ins_cursor.insertRow((centroid_xy[0],centroid_xy[1],bearing_angle,radius))
    del ins_cursor

    #projected coordinate system used for output lines feature classes generated
    project_coordsys = """PROJCS['NAD_1927_StatePlane_Alabama_East_FIPS_0101',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1927',
    DATUM['D_North_American_1927',SPHEROID['Clarke_1866',6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],
    UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],
    PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-85.83333333333333],
    PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.99996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',30.5],
    UNIT['Foot_US',0.3048006096012192]];-17948200 -43887100 3048,00609601219;
    -100000 10000;-100000 10000;3,28083333333333E-03;0,001;0,001;IsHighPrecision"""

    arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(bearing_table,clip_lines_fc,"Xcoord","Ycoord",
                                           "Distance","Feet","Bearing",spatial_reference=project_coordsys)
    #adding each circle's 8 lines in iteration to the sum output line feature class
    arcpy.Append_management(clip_lines_fc,sum_lines_fc,"NO_TEST")

    #deleting temp feature classes to avoid locking issues at next iteration
    arcpy.Delete_management(bearing_table)
    arcpy.Delete_management(clip_lines_fc)

#cutting each circle in the polygon feature class by using the lines obtained earlier
arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management([in_poly_fc,sum_lines_fc],"Quadrants","#","ATTRIBUTES","#")
```

The source polygon feature class with circles:

[image]

The processed circles, each divided into 8 segments:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for your script Alex, very nice!

I saw a small issue, since relies on several geoprocessing tools that run for *each* row: Create Table > Add Field > Cursor to Insert Rows > Bearing Distance To Line > Append > Delete Table > Delete Lines >>> Reiterate for next row. It took 10 secs per feature for me. Since, I needed to process around 18,000 features (e.g. 50 hour runtime), it wasn't very scalable.

I also encountered the problem of FeatureToPolygon_management creating slivers because it planarized all the pie segments such that each overlap became its own small polygon (see below). It also requires an *Advanced* license to run (scarce in our group).

[image: Planarization causing slivers]

I expanded on the script to run on any license level and perform all trig calculations directly in Python so we don't have to rely on the GP overhead.

```py
__author__ = "John K. Tran, Michael Tarrant, Alex Tereshenkov"
__contact__ = "jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu, http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/14435/alex-tereshenkov"
__version__ = "3.0"
__created__ = "6/30/15"
__credits__ = "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/how-to-split-circles-in-8-quadrants"

"""Cuts each circle in a circular input polygon feature class (e.g. from a buffer tool) into
pie segments based on a user-specified number of slices."""

import arcpy
import math
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.SetProgressor('default', "Firing up script...")

# Set up initial parameters.
arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Setting up initial parameters")
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # A polygon feature class consisting of circles (e.g. derived from a buffer).
outfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # The output polygon feature class cut into pie pieces.
numslices = arcpy.GetParameter(2) # Defines number of slices to cut each circle.
degrees = [360.0/float(numslices)*i for i in range(0, numslices)]
radians = [deg*(math.pi/180.0) for deg in degrees]
spatialref = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference
finalpies = []

# Calculating pie segments from input. Takes the circle geometry, creates a "cutting line" based on the bearing points and centroid, then cuts the circle geometry, returning the resulting pie segment in the 'finalpies' list.
count1 = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@") as searchcursor:
    for row in searchcursor:
        if count1 % 100 == 0:
            arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Calculating pie segments from input: Currently on row {0}".format(str(count1)))
        geom = row[0]
        centroid = geom.trueCentroid
        circumference = geom.length
        radius = circumference/(2*math.pi) # Since Diameter = 2*pi*Radius >>> Radius = Diameter/(2*pi)
        ##radius *= 1.001 # Add an extra bit to ensure closure.
        bearingpoints = []
        cuttinglines = []
        oldbearingpoint = None # Set up an initial old bearing point value to seed the cutting line.
        for radian in radians:
            xcoord = centroid.X + math.sin(radian)*radius # Given a radius and angle, the remaining legs of a right triangle (e.g. the x and y 
            ycoord = centroid.Y + math.cos(radian)*radius # displacement) can be obtained, where x = sin(theta)*radius and y = cos(theta)*radius.
            bearingpoint = arcpy.Point(xcoord, ycoord) # Bearing point is analogous to a polar coordinate system. It's a location with respect to a distance and angle (measured clockwise from north) to a reference point (e.g. the circle centroid).
            bearingpoints.append(bearingpoint)
            if oldbearingpoint:
                cuttingline = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([oldbearingpoint, centroid, bearingpoint]), spatialref) # Cutting line is the line created by connecting the previous bearing point, centroid, and current bearing point to make a pie sector.
                cuttinglines.append(cuttingline)
            oldbearingpoint = bearingpoint
        cuttinglines.append(arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([bearingpoints[-1], centroid, bearingpoints[0]]), spatialref))
        for eachcuttingline in cuttinglines:
            pie1, pie2 = geom.cut(eachcuttingline) # Cut the pie using the native arcpy.Geometry() "cut" method.
            if pie1 and pie2: # Since cutting results in two polygon features (left + right), but we don't know which polygon contains the "pie sector" and which polygon contains "the rest of the pie",
                if pie1.area < pie2.area: # we have to compare their areas. The target pie sector (for slice numbers greater than 2) will be smaller than "the rest of the pie".
                    finalpie = pie1 # If pie1 is smaller, use pie1.
                elif pie1.area > pie2.area:
                    finalpie = pie2 # If pie2 is smaller, use pie2.
                else:
                    raise ArithmeticError("I encountered an internal error - both pieces were the same size and I couldn't identify the target piece from the rest of the pie (e.g. if Number of Slices = 2). See John to troubleshoot.")
            else:
                raise ValueError("I encountered an internal error - the cutting line didn't cut the pie, so one piece evaluated to 'None'. See John to troubleshoot.")
            finalpies.append(finalpie)
        count1 += 1
del searchcursor

# Create a blank polygon feature class and insert each pie sector.
count2 = 1
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), os.path.basename(outfc), "POLYGON", None, "DISABLED", "DISABLED", spatialref)
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, "SHAPE@") as insertcursor:
    for eachpie in finalpies:
        if count2 % 100 == 0:
            arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Writing pie segments to output: Currently on row {0}".format(str(count2)))
        row = (eachpie,)
        insertcursor.insertRow(row)
        count2 += 1
del insertcursor

arcpy.ResetProgressor()
```

It just requires a script tool that accepts as parameters:

1. An input polygon feature class (Type: Feature Class,)
2. An output polygon feature class (Type: Feature Class; Direction: Output)
3. The number of slices to cut the pie (Type: Long)

Or you can run it directly with a few modifications by hard-coding the GetParameterAsText variables and replacing SetProgressorLabel with standard prints.