# Create multiple pizza slice type shape from excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel

I am trying to make pizza type shape with various radious of each slice. Number of slices depend on number of years and radius of each slice depends on number of population. All I know the center longitude-latitude, and radius (num of population). Can anyone let me how to make such shape and how to design the excel sheet?

Comment: What have **you tried** already?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a step-by-step answer, more of an explore-on-your-own answer.

To get your LatLon data into XY coordinates, you would want to "[Display XY](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm)" the excel table and save the event layer as a feature class.

After that, there are several options you'll want to explore.

1. There's a tool in [ET GeoWizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_MainFeatures.htm) called "Points To Pie Segments" that may be useful to you. I'm not sure if ET GeoWizards is free-ware or pay-ware. There's a free version, but it's limited and might not have that specific tool you're looking for.
2. You can create a buffer around your points using the "Years" field you have in the **buffer_distance_or_field** parameter to create variable-radii buffers. Then depending on your Python scripting experience, try reading [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/how-to-split-circles-in-8-quadrants/152988#152988) on GSE and see if you can implement a slicing algorithm with a few modifications to the existing script. You mainly want a variable slice number depending on your field [population] rather than a hard-coded one.

Comment: Is there any specific tool to draw such shape? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't an out-of-the-box tool to accomplish request 2. The first request - creating variable-radii buffers based off a field - can be accomplished with the normal Buffer tool. The second step - slicing circular buffers into a variable-number of sectors based off another field - is rather unconventional and I know of no way without scripting. The ET GeoWizard tool cuts circles into a _fixed_ number of sectors. The code in answer 2 _can_ cut circles into variable sectors, but you have to modify it to accomplish what you need. Good opportunity to learn Python.