# How to split a circle in equal parts in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, vector, geometry

I'm looking to split a circle polygon generated by a buffer around a point in equal parts. The goal is to be able to calculate statistics about the raster that will be under the circle for each part of the circle.

[This post explains how to do it for a square polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23688/how-to-split-a-vector-in-equal-smaller-parts-in-qgis-or-similar) and [this one how to do it with arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/how-to-split-circles-in-8-quadrants), but does anyone know how can I achieve a similar thing with a circle AND with QGIS ?

Comment: I guess the most "simple" way would be to translate the script from your second link to PyQGIS. This requires a relatively good knowledge of PyQGIS though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very easy to do with [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html). The secret is the [union](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.union) predicate which divides the lines in segments at each intersection.

[image]

The Polygon is converted to a LinearRing or LineString an the union is done.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon
# union of the line and the LinearRing of the Polygon
result = line.union(LineString(list(polygon.exterior.coords)))
```

The result is a MultiLineString

[image: Now]

Now we can use use the [polygonize](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#other-operations) function

```
from shapely.ops import polygonize
for geom in polygonize(result):
    .....
```

Result

[image]

In PyQGIS the [combine](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#afb59c7e96a7335b3caa9fa952523ecc4) predicate is the equivalent of union, see [Python: Union selected polygons in a layer](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Python-Union-selected-polygons-in-a-layer-td5081862.html))

```
ring = poly.asPolygon()[0]
linearRing = ring.asPolyline()
result = line.combine(linearRing)
```

The result is the same MultiLineString but PyQGIS has no polygonize function. There is an algorithm in the Processing Toobox (qgis:polygonize) but it crashes with MultiLineStrings in my case. So I continue to use shapely.